Converting a Multi Page TIFF Document to a PDF Using lowagie itext
Does anyone know how to convert all of the pages in a multi page TIFF document to a PDF using lowagie itext 2.1.7?

Step 1:
Read your input file and split the TIFF into individual (single) images. You can write them out to individual files or keep them as byte arrays if you have enough memory. See sample code here how TIFFs can be split
Trying to improve multi-page TIFF file splitting
Step 2:
Create 1 multipage PDF or create individual PDF pages from the images and combine them to a multipage PDF.
Sample Convert Image into Pdf using itextsharp in c#

The simplest way is to use any application that reads TIFF and programmatically Prints PDF. There are many so in the past as a supporter may have suggested SumatraPDF XP viewer as a good candidate. However it no longer does that. Cross platforms you could use Image Magick.
For Windows Users there are many much easier to use similar programmable viewers such as IrfanView.

